# Averaging values in a list of a list of a list in Python

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm working on a method to average data from multiple files and put the results into a single file.  Each line of the files looks like:

File #1

```
Test1,5,2,1,8
Test2,10,4,3,2
...
```

File #2

```
Test1,2,4,5,1
Test2,4,6,10,3
...
```

Here is the code I use to store the data:

```
totalData = []
for i in range(0, len(files)):
    data = []
    if ".csv" in files[i]:
        infile = open(files[i],"r")
        temp = infile.readline()

        while temp != "":               
            data.append([c.strip() for c in temp.split(",")])
            temp = infile.readline()            

        totalData.append(data)
```

So what I'm left with is totalData looking like the following:

```
totalData = [[
             [Test1,5,2,1,8],
             [Test2,10,4,3,2]],
             [[Test1,2,4,5,1],
             [Test2,4,6,10,3]]]
```

What I want to average is for all Test1, Test2, etc, average all the first values and then the second values and so forth.  So testAverage would look like:

```
testAverage = [[Test1,3.5,3,3,4.5],
               [Test2,7,5,6.5,2.5]]
```

I'm struggling to think of a concise/efficient way to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated!  Also, if there are better ways to manage this type of data, please let me know.

Comment: `Test1` is a string in the list?

Comment: Yes, Test1, Test2, etc are strings in the list.   The rest of the values are integers/doubles

Comment: you know you can just do `for line in filehandle:` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just need two loops

```
totalData = [ [['Test1',5,2,1,8],['Test2',10,4,3,2]],
                  [['Test1',2,4,5,1],['Test2',4,6,10,3]] ]
for t in range(len(totalData[0])): #tests
    result = [totalData[0][t][0],]
    for i in range(1,len(totalData[0][0])): #numbers
        sum = 0.0
        for j in range(len(totalData)):
            sum += totalData[j][t][i]
        sum /= len(totalData)
        result.append(sum)
    print result
```

Comment: This produces the result: `['Test1', 3, 3, 3, 4]; ['Test2', 7, 5, 6, 2]`, no? You seem to have omitted a mechanism to convert from ints to floats.

Answer (score 1):

first flatten it out

```
results = itertools.chain.from_iterable(totalData)
```

then sort it

```
results.sort()
```

then use groupby

```
data = {}
for key,values in itertools.groupby(results,lambda x:x[0]):
    columns = zip(*values)
    data[key] = [sum(c)*1.0/len(c) for c in columns]
```

and finally just print your `data`

Answer (score 0):

If your data structure is regular, the best is probably to use numpy. You should be able to install it with pip from the terminal

```
pip install numpy
```

Then in python:

```
import numpy as np
totalData = np.array(totalData)
# remove the last dimension (i.e. 'Test1', 'Test2'), since it's not a number
totalData = np.array(totalData[:, :, 1:], float)
# average
np.mean(totalData, axis=0)
```